# Парсинг строки для разбиения на слова по пробелу

Tags: sql, oracle

Не могу найти красивого решения для вычленения слов из строки. Например:

```
SELECT 'Фамилия' as Col_1,  Parse(FullName, ' ')[0] as FirstName,
       'Имя' as Col_2,      Parse(FullName, ' ')[1] as Name,
       'Отчество' as Col_3, Parse(FullName, ' ')[2] as Patronymic
FROM Students
```

Есть ли подобное в SQL вообще без написания своих хранимых функций?

Comment: Ну простое деление по пробелу с оставлением группы с известным номером несложно организовать. Тем же `REGEXP_REPLACE()` например...

Comment: Читаю сейчас про регулярные выражения. Мощно. Пока не совсем понял как использовать, но, думаю через шаблоны вполне можно вытащить нужное слово. Меня только смущает, что каждый раз будет вызываться функция, а не один раз за строку распарсить и потом вытаскивать нужный элемент. Ну ладно, и таааак сойдет. Наверное. :)

Comment: "а не один раз за строку распарсить" - сделайте один  раз в подзапросе и потом вытаскивайте нужный элемент, ничто не  мешает.

Comment: Не совсем понятно - "для вычленения только одного слова из строки" - и тут же в примере вы пытаетесь достать три слова.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно обойтись без регулярок, используя только `substr` и `instr`. Несмотря на свою неказистость, такое решение может показывать значительно более высокую скорость по сравнение с регулярками.

```
with Students as (
    select level id, 'fname'||level||' mname'||level||' lname'||level fullName from dual  
    connect by level <= 3
)
select s.*,
       substr(s.fullName, 1, instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 1) - 1 ) as fName,
       substr(s.fullName, instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 1),  instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 2) - instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 1) ) as mName,
       substr(s.fullName, instr(s.fullName, ' ', 1, 2) ) as lName
  from Students s
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
with Students as (
    select level id, 'fname'||level||' mname'||level||' lname'||level fullName from dual  
    connect by level <= 3
),
params as (select '(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)' namePattern from dual),
studentNames as (
    select id,
        regexp_replace (fullName, namePattern, '\1') fName,   
        regexp_replace (fullName, namePattern, '\2') mName,   
        regexp_replace (fullName, namePattern, '\3') lName 
    from Students, params
)
select * from studentNames
;

        ID FNAME      MNAME      LNAME    
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 fname1     mname1     lname1    
         2 fname2     mname2     lname2    
         3 fname3     mname3     lname3
```

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на основаниии совета @Akina (только REGEXP_SUBSTR вместо REGEXP_REPLACE).

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(FULL_NAME,'[^ ]+',1,1) AS SURNAME
      ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(FULL_NAME,'[^ ]+',1,2) AS NAME
      ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(FULL_NAME,'[^ ]+',1,3) AS PATRONYMIC
FROM STUDENTS
```